# How to create a procedural embedded stone texture for ground/asphalt/pebbled concrete?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

I'm trying to make some ground like or some asphalt like this procedurally in cycles; however, I don't have a good way to make the stones:

[image]
<sub>Ignore the large pebbles and the pine needles</sub>

[image]

[image]

Is there a good controllable solution? 
The important things here are that the stones are **distinct** (both shape and color), **adjustable in size**, are distinct form the ground and can  be **sharp edged** or **round edged** (sharp edged *is* a requirement). Its really important that these stones look reasonable up close and that they are controllable.

To anyone thinking about using a voronoi texture, You will have to come up with some serious ways t alter it, as it stands, it has little promise, I tried:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the other voronoi texture type?

Comment: @TARDISMaker I used both of them to make that image

Comment: Pretty good question, but it's a little unclear exactly what you're after. Do you want a stony cement or do you want asphalt (or something in between)? The examples you provided look like both, so a person answering might be turned off, especially on this kind of site.

Comment: @SimonHeggie Both of those materials are made with stones embedded in settling liquid (that becomes hard). What I'm trying to do is find a good way of making the stones (that isn't fudging it). Sorry for not being clear. I have made some edits that hopefully clarify the goal a little better.

Comment: Now you have more chance of being answered :)

Comment: @GiantCowFilms, I understand why you want the procedural texture, but I'm curious to know exactly where you want to apply this texture. I had a similar challenge when working with masonry--when a brick wall was close to a viewer I wanted the joint lines between individual bricks to be visible to the degree that the indentations at the mortar joints were perceptible. But beyond a modest distance, perhaps 5 meters, or so, the mortar joints will be visible, but the geometry of the joint will not, so on anything further away, a 2D image suffices. It seems to me that Asphalt would be quite similar.

Comment: @brasshat I want this for close up renderings (about the distances you see in the photo. I have already managed to get decent results fudging it from a distance: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BcybT.jpg

Comment: I think I would use a procedural texture for the dirt or other material between the stones, then for the embedded stones in the first and third pictures you posted above, model the stones embedded in the dirt. I wouldn't model the whole stone, just a little bit more than shows above the dirt. The stones could be created by a script which would allow the user to control the size of the stone, and the distance between adjacent stones, and depending upon the type of rock each stone is supposed to represent, the stones could have a material and texture applied, too.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using *Brick Texture* as a core for stones generation. I've set up these nodes for some tests:
[image: stones nodes]

As you see I use *Voronoi* too (because you mentioned it) but just to shuffle the stones a little bit. I'm sure you can use noise or something else for it.

This gives us the sharp shapes we were after. We can use it as a mask then: [image: mask]

I multiply it by some color, mix with another instances of this "stones texture" with a bit different sizes/frequencies/color and finally add a simple noisy background. I also apply some *Image Blur* from [b°wide NodePack](https://bwide.wordpress.com/node-groups/bwide-nodepack-for-blender/)
[image: stones1]
Personally, I like it when the stones are small and I'm not sure if you'll be satisfied with it much zoomed.
[image: small stones]

I also did't manage to reach the stones density as on your 2nd image without ending with many overlapping stones.
Here's my general set-up:
[image: General nodes]

UPDATE:
To make it more clear how **Bricks-Voronoi pair** works I'll give some more images of *Bricks* without its companion.
No vector input (raw boring squares):
[image: raw]
*Noise texture*:
[image: Noise]
*Wave texture*:
[image: Wave]

Comment: I'm curious how feeding the Voronoi texture into the vector for the brick texture works.... Otherwise this is definitely a good starting point, although I think it may need still a little more refinement

Comment: Well, vector alters location, form and overall pattern of the "bricks" drawn. I'll update the answer with images now.

Comment: I stopped at *Voronoi* because I could get aSTONishing look much easier with it ;-)
Sure it needs a lot more tweaking to get the final look. I'm still in research.